# dependency injection - static methods

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, static-methods

I am trying to find the right design pattern for the below scenario.

I have a dataaccess class that can access different datasource. So I have designed to have an implementation class for each datasource(DataAccessMongo, DataAccesssql).

Based on the configuration change the data source must be switched. I believe the right way to do this is to use dependency injection and the data access class that have must accept an interface as a dependency. In the below scenario all the methods are static and I am unable to have a static method in an interface. So for now I am using a enum to check what is the data access type and call the corresponding method. If there are more data sources then definitely I should add more conditions for each data source. I would like a to arrive at a better design pattern. Please suggest what will be the best patter for this scenario. Thanks.

```
//Implementation class for Mongo
Public Class DataAccessMongo 
{
    public static string FindById(string itemId)
    {
    ...
    }
    public static string FindByName(string itemId)
    {
    ...
    }
    public static string FindByLastName(string itemId)
    {
    ...
    }
}

//Implementation class for Sql
Public Class DataAccessSql
{
    public static string FindById(string itemId)
    {
    ...
    }
    public static string FindByName(string itemId)
    {
    ...
    }
    public static string FindByLastName(string itemId)
    {
    ...
    }
}


Public Class DataAccess
{
    public static string FindById(string id)
    {
            string result = string.Empty;

            if (databaseType == EnumDb.Mongo)
            {
                result = DataAccessMongo.FindById(id);
            }
            else if (databaseType == EnumDb.Sql){
                result = DataAccessSql.FindById(id);
            }

            return result;
    }
    public static string FindByName(string itemId)
    {
            string result = string.Empty;

            if (databaseType == EnumDb.Mongo)
            {
                result = DataAccessMongo.FindByName(id);
            }
            else if (databaseType == EnumDb.Sql){
                result = DataAccessSql.FindByName(id);
            }

            return result;
    }
    public static string FindByLastName(string itemId)
    {
            string result = string.Empty;

            if (databaseType == EnumDb.Mongo)
            {
                result = DataAccessMongo.FindByLastName(id);
            }
            else if (databaseType == EnumDb.Sql){
                result = DataAccessSql.FindByLastName(id);
            }

            return result;
    }

}
```

Note: These methods serve the web API methods.

Comment: How about not using static methods, and instead write an `IDataAccess` interface and different implementations? Then use DI to supply concrete implementations (which, likely, you can configure in your DI bindings as singletons).

Comment: These methods are used to serve feed request and there will be only one data access method called for each request.

Comment: @spender thanks for suggesting singleton. Since there are 14 million request a day and the code will be deployed in a web farm. Will I have to worry more on thread safety when I implement singleton.

Comment: ninject (for instance) offers a "request scope" lifetime, so each request gets a new instance. For data-access, this kind of lifetime might be more appropriate (for instance, EF assumes short context lifetime and should be used in this way). Can't tell if your code will be thread safe or not without intimate understanding of your code.

Comment: @spender, your first comment should be the answer